# Continuity and differentiability for $\sin(\sqrt x)$ & $\sinh(\sqrt {-x})$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ with

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}  {\sin(\sqrt{x})\over\sqrt{x}},&   \text{for } x>0\\
                 1,&                           \text{for } x=0\\
                 {\sinh(\sqrt{-x})\over\sqrt{-x}},& \text{for } x<0.\end{cases}$$

(i) Is $f$ continuous on $\Bbb R$ ?

(ii) Is $f$ differentiable on $\Bbb R$ ?

Well, I don't know whether this works or not:

(i) 
For $x≠0$ $f$ is a composition and an operation of continuous functions.
For $x=0$ both equations $\sin$ and $\sinh$ have the same limit $1$.
So $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$.

(ii)Here I'm not sure:
For $x≠0$ f is a composition and an operation of direffentiable functions
And for $x=0$ ?

Thanks in advance and sorry for Latex,I haven't worked much with it.

Comment: Please improve your formatting.

Comment: $\sqrt x / \sqrt x = 1$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: Now it's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the definition of (lateral) derivative:
$$f'(0+)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})/\sqrt{x}-1}{x-0} = \cdots$$
$$f'(0-)=\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\sinh(\sqrt{-x})/\sqrt{-x}-1}{x-0} = \cdots$$

EDIT: maybe interesting: a plotting of $x\mapsto\sin(\sqrt{|x|})/\sqrt{|x|}$ and $x\mapsto\sinh(\sqrt{|x|})/\sqrt{|x|}$:
[image]

Comment: So if the limit would be 1 it would be differentiable and if not then not ?

Comment: @pinkpanther5, if the limit **exists**.

Answer (score 1):

From the series definition of both functions, $\sin$ and $\sinh$, you get that
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^k}{(2k+1)!}
$$
which, analogous to the exponential series, has infinite radius of convergence.

One might also note that
$$
\sinh(iz)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}2=i\sin(z)
$$
so that one might also recognize from this fact that the parts of $f$ really are the same function.